# Can I no longer see my view counts in the new dashboard?

Tags: carto, statistics

The inset graphic shows the relative up and down of each day's views, but I can't see any numbers. I'd love to continue tracking my monthly stats.

Answer (score 1):

The option is available again! :-) It was removed temporarily due to the new redesign of the CartoDB dashboard.

Now it shows a bar graph with hover information for the map views of each visualization.